# 1 week ago my Wordpress website suddenly started using the theme's default CSS instead of my custom CSS in mobile browsers only

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

My Wordpress website is using the default WooCommerce Storefront theme, but I have completely changed the look of the website with custom CSS. It was looking great in all browsers until about 1 week ago.

Suddenly, it will only display the site using the Storefront theme's default CSS on mobile browsers (it still looks just as it should on desktop/laptop and my Windows tablet). I haven't made any changes to my CSS since it was working a week ago, but I had recently installed the W3 Total Cache plug-in - I somewhat suspect that plug-in is what first caused the issue (specifically enabling Minifying the CSS, HTML & jQuery), but I deactivated it and it still doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

I'm not a web developer and am just now learning a lot of things and trying to maintain my own website, so there's a very real possibility that I have made some error in my CSS or HTML that is causing this to happen!

Here's my website: https://www.thewelllovedlife.com.

I've tried it in several mobile browsers and it's broken in every single one; but it displays fine in most mobile browser emulators that you can use from a desktop.

Comment: The mobile theme is part of the **Jetpack** plugin. Go to **Jetpack** > **Settings** > **Writing tab** > scroll down to the **Theme Enhancements** section  >
Find the **Optimize your site for smartphones** option and click the dropdown arrow >
Select your desired options, then click **Save Settings** ~  Future Reference: [Jetpack Mobile Theme](https://jetpack.com/support/mobile-theme/)

Comment: That did it - thank you so much! I've been trying everything to fix this for a few hours now, and this was such a simple solution! You're a life-saver!

Comment: no problem. I'm glad you got that sorted out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's showing mobile theme of your site. you can disable it.

go to Appearance → Mobile in your WP Admin dashboard and select “No” for “Enable mobile theme” option.

Or

It's a mobile theme coming from Jetpack plugin. Go to Jetpack > Settings > Writing tab > scroll down to the Theme Enhancements section > Find the Optimize your site for smartphones option and click the dropdown arrow > Select your desired options, then click Save Settings ~ Future Reference: Jetpack Mobile Theme

Comment: I don't seem to have a "mobile" option in my Appearance menu. The only options in that section of the menu are Themes, Customize, Widgets, Menus, Header, Background, Premium Themes, Edit CSS, Storefront, and Editor.

Comment: do you have jetpack plugin if so then you have to disable mobile theme in that this link will help [https://jetpack.com/support/mobile-theme/](https://jetpack.com/support/mobile-theme/)